# How to show a fullscreen box popup after 2 mins of inactivity

Tags: javascript

I'm not an expert developer, but I need to show a fullscreen popup after 2 mins of inactivity.
Someone can help me with JavaScript?

I put some example code below

Which CSS property I must give to the div? How can I connect with the JavaScript?

Thanks

```
<div class="my-popup">
  <p>Some example text</p>
</div>

<style>
.my-popup{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:orange;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to achieve it. Start a timer (in below example it's for 5 secs) and if any user event occur (eg. `onmousemove`, `onkeypress` etc.) before these 5 secs, reset the timer again. If no event gets triggered, show the popup after 5 secs by updating the `display` property using JS.

**Full working code snippet:**

```js
let inactivityTime = function() {
  let time;
  window.onload = resetTimer;
  document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
  document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

  function showPopup() {
    document.getElementById('my-popup').style.display = 'block';
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    document.getElementById('my-popup').style.display = 'none';

    clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(showPopup, 5000)
  }
};
inactivityTime();
```

```css
#my-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #fcb603;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-popup">
  <p>You were inactive for 5 seconds</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it runs perfectly.
I asked you another thing: when the popup is open, how can I close it and at the same time redirect to a specific link?

Thanks a lot, you're amazing

Comment: That's great. To close it you can use the ```document.getElementById('my-popup').style.display = 'none';``` line whenever you want to hide the popup. And to redirect to a specific link you can try ```window.location.href = "url"``` (may be inside the showPopup function).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of activity you're talking about..

It could be scrolling, clicking, mouse movements .. or even all

To capture that you're gonna need to have a listener on these events and after a certain time of the events not happening, you display the alert..

Here I've used jquery to access the elements

```js
$(function(){
    function showpopup(time){
        $('.my-popup').addClass('show')
        $('.my-popup').children('p').html(`Inactivity for ${time}`)
        $('#display').html(`Inactivity: Popup Triggered`)
        return false
    }
    activity_status = false
    // Create variable to hold current activity
    // false for no activity and true for activity happening
    $(window).on('mousemove click scroll', function(){
        $('#display').html(`Activity happening, so no popup`)
        // for any of these events, update the activity status
        activity_status = true
        // then when the user begins activity again, close the popup
        $('.my-popup').removeClass('show')
    })
    setInterval(() => {
        // if the activity is false after every 5 seconds, show the modal
        // if not, then set the activity_status to false again and begin checking again
        activity_status = !activity_status ? showpopup('4 seconds') : false
    }, 4000)
})
```

```css
.my-popup {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:orange;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="display"></p>
<div class="my-popup">
  <p></p>
</div>
```